# remove stdClass Object and count(post_id) from stdClass Object ( [count(post_id)] => 1 ) need only result 1

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

My mysql query is:

```
$query=('SELECT count(post_id)  FROM comments where   post_id='.$row['post_id']);
 $usercomments = $this->db->query($query);
 foreach ($usercomments->result() as $comments)
```

Output I got:

```
stdClass Object ( [count(post_id)] => 1 )
```

How can I get  count value 1? how to print?

Comment: i just need  row counts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query to:

```
SELECT count(post_id)  FROM comments where   post_id='.$row['post_id'];
```

to

```
SELECT count(post_id) as post_count  FROM comments where   post_id='.$row['post_id'];
//here post_count is an ALIAS for the count(post_id)
```

and then get its value like:

```
$comments->post_count;
```

Comment: Sounds great !!

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
$comments = (array)$comments;
$count = reset($comments);

var_dump($count); // => 1
```

Note: `reset` returns the first value of an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can get values that contains PHP characters using getting with strings:

```
$usercomments->{"count(post_id)"};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use alias

```
$query=('SELECT count(post_id) as numberPost  FROM comments where   post_id='.$row['post_id']);
$usercomments = $this->db->query($query);
 foreach ($usercomments->result() as $comments)
```

So you can access to the object like this

```
comments->numberPost
```